# Error in displaying read message from modem to listview(index was outside the bounds of the array)

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to develop an SMS application in VB.NET that sends and receives using a modem. The system is able to read the messages on the sim card all right but is not able to display them in the listview. I keep on getting the error index was outside the bounds of the array.

This is my code for loading the respective columns like status,date and messages into the listview. All works except the message column. Thanks.

```
Private Sub ReadMsg()
        Try
            Dim lineoftext As String
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim arytextfile() As String
            lineoftext = rcvdata.ToString
            arytextfile = Split(lineoftext, "+CMGL", , CompareMethod.Text)
            For i = 2 To UBound(arytextfile)
                Dim input As String = arytextfile(i)
                Dim result() As String
                Dim pattern As String = "(:)|(,"")|("","")"
                result = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
                Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
                Dim concat() As String
                With ListView1.Items.Add("null")
                    'index
                    .SubItems.AddRange(New String() {result(2)})
                    'status
                    .SubItems.AddRange(New String() {result(4)})
                    'number
                    Dim my_string, position As String
                    my_string = result(6)
                    position = my_string.Length - 2
                    my_string = my_string.Remove(position, 2)
                    .SubItems.Add(my_string)
                    'for date and time
                    concat = New String() {result(8) & result(9) & result(10) & result(11) & result(12).Substring(0, 2)}
                    .SubItems.AddRange(concat)
                    **'for the message**
                    Dim lineoftexts As String
                    Dim arytextfiles() As String
                    lineoftexts = arytextfile(i)
                    arytextfiles = Split(lineoftexts, "+32", , CompareMethod.Text)
                    .SubItems.Add(arytextfiles(1))
                End With
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: There's no good reason to be posting that much code. YOU need to start by determining what line throws the exception, what the index was that was out of range and what the valid range is. That needs to be done before posting here and it should give you a pretty good start on solving the issue for itself.  If you still can't do so then you need to post ONLY the relevant code and give us all that information.

Comment: ok thanks for your comment but this is my first time of posting. But i really suspect the problem is from this block                                     
    **'for the message**
                    Dim lineoftexts As String
                    Dim arytextfiles() As String
                    lineoftexts = arytextfile(i)
                    arytextfiles = Split(lineoftexts, "+32", , CompareMethod.Text)
                    .SubItems.Add(arytextfiles(1))
                End With

Comment: There's no need for you to suspect.  You can find out for sure.  If you comment out the exception handler then the IDE will break on the line that throws and you can then simply mouse over variables or use the Autos, Locals, Watch, Immediate, etc, windows to evaluate any expression you need to know the value of.  The debugger is there so that you don't have to guess and so neither do we.

Comment: Personally I would recommend not to use `try..catch` with generic handlers like that while you are in the earlier stages of creating your program. They make debugging much more difficult. You should only use them if you have a useful way of dealing with the error. They should not be used for lazy programming. No offense intended of course.